# How to effeciently select data from two tables?

Tags: performance, postgresql

I have two tables: `A, B`.

`A` has `prisoner_id` and `prisoner_name` columns.

`B` has all other info about prisoners included `prisoner_name` column.

First I select all of the data that I need from `B`:

```
WITH prisoner_datas AS
(SELECT prisoner_name, ... FROM B WHERE ...)
```

Then I want to know all of the `id` of my `prisoner_datas`. To do this I need to combine information by `prisoner_name` column, because it's common for both tables

I did the following

```
SELECT A.prisoner_id, prisoner_datas.prisoner_name, prisoner_datas. ...,
FROM A, prisoner_datas
WHERE A.prisoner_name = prisoner_datas.prisoner_name
```

But it works very slow. How can I improve performance?

Comment: `WITH prisoner_datas AS` ... this isn't MySQL syntax.  Which database are you really using?

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen postgressql

Comment: Why do so many people label Postgres and MySQL together?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I think because StackOverflow's auto-tagging does that and most people don't bother validating the tags

Comment: Ah...OK...maybe SO should change that.  I would have guessed that folks do it because MySQL is popular and they want to get hits.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Add an index on the `prisoner_name` join column in the `B` table.  Then the following join should have some performance improvement:

```
SELECT
    A.prisoner_id,
    B.prisoner_name,
    B.prisoner_datas.id      -- and other columns if needed
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
    ON A.prisoner_name = B.prisoner_name
```

Note here that I used an explicit join syntax here.  It isn't required, and the query plan might not change, but it makes the query easier to read.  I don't think the CTE will change much, but the lack of an index on the join column should be important here.

Comment: Isn't `FROM A, prisoner_datas` an implicit CROSS JOIN in Postgresql?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal No, because that cross join is being restricted in the `WHERE` clause if you look closely.  It is an old style join.

Comment: Is there any changes should I make if table `A` is very-very big and `prisoner_datas` is much much smaller than `A` ?

Comment: You might consider reversing the order of the join, but in any case you need to do a full scan of the first table.  The big deal here is the presence/absence of an index AFAIK.